# Typo3 site to run in kiosk mode

Tags: typo3, kiosk

I have an existing fitness site ( showing exercises on different pieces of equipment) with menus available depending on whether the user is logged in.

Not sure of the best way of doing this but I would like to access the site via a touchscreen kiosk which will show a different welcome page and menus.

I know it can be done as a clone site which would mean copying all the execise data but is there a way for typo3 to recognise the type of device, assign it as a certain user and allow user level control of the content shown?

Regards

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Device detecting is very complicated and TS conditions that should work were removed from TYPO3 core some time ago.

If it is important (and possible) to detect one kind of device you may create your own TS condition (userfunc).

---

But maybe another option would solve your problem:
Configure another page type which gets your modified layout for the start page.
Then you only needs to make sure the inital page is called with that specific page type.

An automatic login will be complicated. maybe it would be possible to use a permanent login, where a session cookie without endtime is stored.

Comment: Thanks Bernd. Your suggestion has made me think that maybe having a different domain kiosk.domain.name and identifying based on the start page as you say

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TYPO3 version 8.7, you could use the extension aoe_ipauth (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/aoe_ipauth/) to automatically log in a user based on IP address. There are several other extensions that do this, but I think most of the others are old and don't work in 8.7. There don't seem to be any that support TYPO3 9.5 yet.

Comment: thanks very much, looks like a good option. I guess this would mean I would need to maintain a list of ( hopefully ) fixed IPs- as I plan to roll out a few but this should be manageable